# Is there any Appeal Process after a Ruling of a Beis Din

Tags: beit-din-court

Granted Avram Avinu didn't accept the initial sentence, but that was regarding a decree of Hashem.

Nowadays, is there in the legal structure an appellate Beis Bin where one can have recourse to have a decision reconsidered?

Historically, are there any examples in Sha"s in that regard?

Also, this is probably going too far, but is there anything like that for a Teshuva? That I would doubt.

Comment: +1 A good point. Since the destruction of the Temple (or abolishment of the Great Sanhedrin), the Jewish juridical system is not hierarchical, therefore, no Beis Din is subordinate to any other, unless it was explicitly established by the latter. In such a system no appeal could exist.

Comment: In addition, nowadays, civil cases in Beis Din are considered arbitrations (you sign a paper, withdrawing any future claims), and as such you also have no right to appeal.

Comment: Regarding Shas, we see that many pupils complained to a "bigger" Rabbi about rulings of other Rabbis. But it is difficult to call them "Beis Din" anyway.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8616/are-jewish-court-rulings-subject-to-appeal

Comment: @AlBerko Why don't you post your comments as an answer so I can upvote it. That may not be relevant, but your remarks would more likely get the attention they deserve as an answer. With kind regards,

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: not really, but there are certain circumstances in which a beit din's decision can be reopened and reviewed.

A more developed answer can be found in two articles on the subject:

- *The Right of Appeal in Talmudic Law* by Arthur Jay Silverstein (available [here](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/214081406.pdf))
- *The Appeal Process in the Jewish Legal System* by J David Bleich (available [here](https://www.sefaria.org/Contemporary_Halakhic_Problems,_Vol_IV,_Chapter_II_The_Appeal_Process_in_the_Jewish_Legal_System))

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, there's nothing in halacha per se, however the Israeli rabbinate courts have such an option, as does the Beth Din of America.

If you get a responsum from Rabbi A and think it's in error, you can explain your concerns to him; and you're also allowed to contact Rabbi B and say *Rabbi A told me ___, what is your opinion?" But generally, rabbis writing responsa don't have a formal hierarchy that you can simply demand "an appeal."

Comment: What is the Halachic rationale for the Israeli rabbinate courts and the BDA's approach?